# Faster way to check for value in csv?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some code that looks up from a csv, then goes to retrieve it from google maps if it's not present in the csv.  I have 100,000+ records and it's taking ~2 hours.  Any ideas on how to speed this up?  Thanks!

```
from csv import DictReader
import codecs

def find_school(high_school, city, state):
    types_of_encoding = ["utf8"]
    for encoding_type in types_of_encoding:
        with codecs.open('C:/high_schools.csv', encoding=encoding_type, errors='replace') as csvfile:
            reader = DictReader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
            #checks the csv file and sees if the high school already exists
                if (row['high_school'] == high_school.upper() and
                    row['city'] == city.upper() and
                    row['state'] == state.upper()):
                    return dict(row)['zipcode'],dict(row)['latitude'],dict(row)['longitude'],dict(row)['place_id']
                else:
                    #hits Google Maps api
#executes
df['zip'],df['latitude'], df['longitude'], df['place_id'] = zip(*df.apply(lambda row: find_school(row['high_school'].strip(), row['City'].strip(), row['State'].strip()), axis=1))
```

CSV FILE SNIPPET

```
high_school,city,state,address,zipcode,latitude,longitude,place_id,country,location_type
GEORGIA MILITARY COLLEGE,MILLEDGEVILLE,GA,"201 E GREENE ST, MILLEDGEVILLE, GA 31061, USA",31061,33.0789184,-83.2235169,ChIJv0wUz97H9ogRwuKm_HC-lu8,USA,UNIVERSITY
BOWIE,BOWIE,MD,"15200 ANNAPOLIS RD, BOWIE, MD 20715, USA",20715,38.9780387,-76.7435378,ChIJRWh2C1fpt4kR6XFWnAm5yAE,USA,SCHOOL
EVERGLADES,MIRAMAR,FL,"17100 SW 48TH CT, MIRAMAR, FL 33027, USA",33027,25.9696495,-80.3737813,ChIJQfmM_I6j2YgR1Hdq0CC4apo,USA,SCHOOL
```

Comment: How many times does this code have to query Google maps?

Comment: (1) Please provide example data to work with, even if it's just a small subset of the CSV you're working with (or alternately provide fake data that represents your use case).  (2) You tagged `pandas`, but your code doesn't use Pandas.

Comment: Google maps builds this csv, so the first time it hits it a lot, then every subsequent run it almost never hits google api.

Comment: I use pandas in my analysis but did not use it for the csv lookup.  I'm open to a pandas solution though.  That's why I tagged.  I provided 3 rows of the csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point reading the file every single time you want to make a check. Just load the file once into memory and create a new dictionary with the fields you're interested in as part of a tuple key.

```
import csv

lookup_dict = {}
with open('C:/Users/Josh/Desktop/test.csv') as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    for row in reader:
        lookup_dict[(row['high_school'].lower(), row['city'].lower(),
                    row['state'].lower())] = row
```

Now you only have to check whether a value you want to test for is already a key in `lookup_dict`. If it's not, then you query Google Maps.

Since your edit shows that you're using this to `apply` to a dataframe, you should calculate `lookup_dict` outside of the function and pass it as an argument. That way, the file is still only read once.

```
lookup_dict = {}
with open('C:/Users/Josh/Desktop/test.csv') as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    for row in reader:
        lookup_dict[(row['high_school'].lower(), row['city'].lower(),
                    row['state'].lower())] = row

def find_school(high_school, city, state, lookup_dict):
    result = lookup_dict.get((high_school.lower(), city.lower(), state.lower()))
    if result:
        return result
    else:
        # Google query
        pass

a = find_school('georgia military college', 'milledgeville', 'ga', lookup_dict)
#df['zip'],df['latitude'], df['longitude'], df['place_id'] = zip(*df.apply(lambda row: find_school(row['high_school'].strip(), row['City'].strip(), row['State'].strip()), axis=1))
```

Comment: I just added how I execute it.  Can you quickly look at that?

Comment: @nonegiven72 edited. I'm not sure I understand exactly how your `return` works, I've just stored the whole row against the key to illustrate the principle. You might need to modify what is returned.

Comment: I have a stupid question.  How can I have the file open to pass it in?  Would the "with open('......')" have to precede the "def find_school(.....)".  And would the "def find_school()" need to be indented due to the with open?

Comment: @nonegiven72 not a stupid question, but I think you're going way off course. The file isn't still open. These are two completely independent activities. Once you've made `lookup_dict` you can completely forget about the file. Just create `lookup_dict` in the global scope.

Comment: @nonegiven72 just put my first block of code above your current `find_school` function. Don't indent the function to be within the `with` block.

Comment: @nonegiven72 I've edited to make the structure clear. You just need to fix exactly what fields you store in `lookup_dict` (like I said, I'm just storing the whole dictionary representing a row)

Comment: Just tried it out in a simplistic form and it seemed to work. Thanks for everything

Comment: That reduced the run time from hours to about a minute. Thanks again!

Comment: @nonegiven72 I knew it would be substantial, I was going to ask for you to report back. Thanks for reporting back :)